# Eclipse: Play Framework 2 - how to hide or move dependencies from root folder

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework-2.0

I downloaded the play framework play! 2.1.0 (using Java 1.6.0_23 and Scala 2.10.0)

it seems that `play eclipsify` is no longer working but `play eclipse` is working

however the project generated is not very nice *all the dependencies are shown in the root*.

Isn't there a way to generate it with a maven like library called dependencies which will store all the dependencies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside eclipse.. `Window -> Show view -> Package explorer`

All files and folders aligned nicely, haven't had any issues when using it :)

Answer (score 1):

The command is now called `eclipse`: `play eclipse`.

Comment: That wasn't the question. He (she?) already has the right command but it isn't generating what he wants. I highlighted the console commands in the original question to make that clearer.

Comment: hi thats not the question, im interested in packaging all the dependencies in one folder

Comment: Sorry, shot too early... I also know this issue. It's annoying to have them all in the main folder. I had it also once, but can't remember the solution.

Comment: Check out my answer if you are still fighting with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Usually my "ultimate" solution is this:

```
eclipse with-source=true execution-environment=JavaSE-1.7
```

Source codes of libraries will be available from eclipse. Use your jdk version for execution-environment. (Note that autocomple is avaliable in Play console as well, pressing TAB usually helps you a lot)

Answer (score 0):

I guess there is no solution to making play group dependencies in one folder - maven style

thanks though